# Hash of arrays - how to sort both keys and elements of arrays?

Tags: ruby

How can I sort both keys and elements of arrays in hash like this?

`{3=>[5, 1, 4], 1=>[3, 2, 1], 6=>[1, 3, 2]}`

So I get:

`{1=>[1,2,3], 3=>[1,4,5], 6=>[1,2,3]}`

Comment: It's not duplicate, I want it to sort keys in hash AND elements in array. Anyway I think I found an answer: `Hash[h.map{|a,b| [a,[b.sort]]}.sort]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd do

```
# in >= 2.1
hash.sort_by(&:first).map { |k, v| [k, v.sort]}.to_h
# => {1=>[1, 2, 3], 3=>[1, 4, 5], 6=>[1, 2, 3]}
# in < 2.1
Hash[hash.sort_by(&:first).map { |k, v| [k, v.sort]}]
# => {1=>[1, 2, 3], 3=>[1, 4, 5], 6=>[1, 2, 3]}
```

Answer (score 4):

I find this easy to read:

```
x.map{|k,v|[k,v.sort]}.sort.to_h
```

Comment: Nah! Dude. It is not easy to read. When you are saying `#sort`, it is not clearly telling sort by what ?? Guest/Reader has to go to the IRB to play and find out _how is it_ doing. Less code means not always _easy_ and _nice_. In this example as by the OP, `#sort_by` much cleaner IMO.

Answer (score 0):

Just thought packaging [Arup](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2767755/arup-rakshit)'s answer may help in reusing the functionality:

```
module KeyValueSorter
  def sort_all
    Hash[sort_by(&:first).map { |k, v| [k, v.sort]}]
  end
end

hash = {3=>[5, 1, 4], 1=>[3, 2, 1], 6=>[1, 3, 2]}

hash.extend(KeyValueSorter).sort_all # => {1=>[1, 2, 3], 3=>[1, 4, 5], 6=>[1, 2, 3]}
```